# Nulling a Referenced Array Item From a Function

Tags: php

How can I reference an array item from a function in php? I would also like to make that array item null.

Is this correct?

```
 <?php
    $array = array();
    function nullItem($item) {
        $item = null;
    }
    class foo
    {
        function do_foo()
        {
            echo "Doing foo.";
        }
    }
    $array[0] = new foo;
    var_dump($array);
    nullItem($array[0]);
    var_dump($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
function nullItem(&$item){
    $item = NULL;
}
```

which passes the item by reference with [`&`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and turns `$item`/`$array[0]` to `NULL`

Comment: That '&' passes the variable by reference?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a fancy function just use PHP's **unset** :

```
unset($array[0]);
```

Comment: this does answer the question of how to reference an array item from a function.